How can I share object mesh data but with different origins?
I have a wheel object who's origin needs to be at the world center (requirement for the BeamNG game engine physics). I want to make linked duplicates with Alt+D so I need to only edit one wheel mesh data and automatically reflect on all other wheels.

So I start making a linked duplicate of the rear left blue/gray wheel then rotate the duplicate by 180 degrees then move it on the y-axis so it is positioned like in the left picture. But the origin will naturally be away from the world origin. If I then set origin to 3D cursor, It will also set the origin on the original object which will make it flip to another location as shown on the right pic. Is it possible to have different objects share mesh data but have different origin? How can I fix this dilemma?


No you can't but you can either parent the new wheels to empties or break the link?

Only way to have that is using Geometry Nodes.
Use a Transform Geometry node right after the base geometry input, and use the transform parameters to scale, rotate, or translate geometry as needed.
Have in mind that while the geometry will be kept in sync inside Blender, technically those will no longer be instances of each other, and from an exporter standpoint will effectively be exported as independent objects.
From a workflow point of view through, while inside Blender they will for most intents and purposes behave as duplicate instances.

You cannot have different origins for the same "mesh".
But you can put this origin at the center of the cart and create 4 rotated copies.
The weird position you saw is actually one of the positions you want. You just need two more copies.

Thank you for your post. Yeah but this will only work if it's perfectly symmetrical the front and back. Yeah but the origin has to be at the world center for the physics engine from beamng to work on these objects.

So the answer is "no", you can't, @MeganLove

Well it is possible using GN :D
